# How to implement typesafe callback system in Scala?

Tags: oop, scala, callback

I have a client-server application connected via sockets. My MessageHandler class is responsible for handling incoming and outgoing messages. I pass arguments necessary to fill request and callback which I would like to be invoked after response will be received. I store callback in hash map with unique request identifier. When response received I get callback from hash map, invoke it and pass response as argument. Here is the code

```
class MessageHanlder {
  val callbacks = new HashMap[String, (AnyRef) => Unit]

  def sendAuthRequest(login: String, password: String, callback: Option[(AnyRef) => Unit]) {
    val requestId = generateRequestId()
    // create a packet with requestId, login and password
    // send the packet
    if(callback.isDefined) callbacks += ((requestId, callback.get))
  }

  private def generateRequestId() = // returns random string

  def handleAuthResponse(authResponse: AuthResponse) {
    val requestId = authResponse.requestId
    val callbackOption = callbacks.get(requestId)
    if(callbackOption.isDefined) callbackOption.get(authResponse)
  }

  def sendServerInfoRequest(callback: Option[(AnyRef) => Unit]) {
    val requestId = generateRequestId()
    // create a packet with requestId
    // send the packet
    if(callback.isDefined) callbacks += ((requestId, callback.get))
  }

  def handleServerInfoResponse(serverInfoResponse: ServerInfoResponse) {
    val requestId = serverInfoResponse.requestId
    val callbackOption = callbacks.get(requestId)
    if(callbackOption.isDefined) callbackOption.get(serverInfoResponse)
  }
```

My problem is argument type for callback. It can be ServerInfoResponse or AuthResponse or any other response type. Each response has its own set of fields which I'd like to access from callback. To save callback into hashmap I have to generalize argument type as AnyRef. So in callback I have to cast AnyRef to concrete type like this

```
val serverInfoCallback = (response: AnyRef) => {
  val serverInfoResponse = response.asInstanceOf[ServerInfoResponse] // explicit cast
  val name = serverInfoResponse.name
  val numberOfCores = serverInfoResponse.numberOfCores
  // so on
}
```

Is there any way to avoid casting? Or is there more correct way to implement callback system?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget your hashmap must allow concurrency correctly, e.g. you might use ConcurrentHasMap as the implementation class instead. Otherwise you face race hazards.

Comment: Thanks Rick, that's really important. However in my real application MessageHandler is Akka actor and regular HashMap is not an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the response type is not statically known you could make a sealed trait Response and have those other types extend it.

Then you could use pattern matching with some compiler guarantees about checking all cases.  If you can't make those types extend one sealed type you could use pattern matching anyway but the compiler won't help you.

If the response type is statically known, could you make the type relationships clear in the question?

Comment: Yes, the response types are statically known and can extend sealed trait Response. Pattern matching here looks like asInstanceOf on steroids but anyway it's better than what I currently have. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I found your question quite interesting and tried to find a type-safe solution using the incredible [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library. Here we go:

#### Basics

```
/* Responses get send to the callbacks */
abstract class Response

/* Callback ids identify callbacks and also specify the type of response
 * a corresponding callback accepts.
 */
abstract class CallbackId[T <: Response]
```

#### Implicits ensuring type-safety

```
/* Shapeless magic that ensures a type-safe mapping from identifiers to
 * callbacks. Consider an implicit of type CME[CallbackId[R], R => Unit]
 * as the evidence that "an id promising to identify a callback that
 * accepts a response R actually maps to such a function."
 */
class CME[-K, V] /* CallbackMapEntry */

implicit val acceptAppleResponse =
  new CME[CallbackId[AppleResponse], AppleResponse => Unit]

implicit val acceptPearResponse =
  new CME[CallbackId[PearResponse], PearResponse => Unit]

implicit val acceptAnyResponse =
  new CME[CallbackId[Response], Response => Unit]
```

#### Responses

```
/* Define some responses */
case class AppleResponse() extends Response
case class PearResponse() extends Response
case class PruneResponse() extends Response
```

#### Callbacks

```
/* Define some callbacks */

val appleResponseCallback1 = (r: AppleResponse) => {
  println("[appleResponseCallback1]")
}

val appleResponseCallback2 = (r: AppleResponse) => {
  println("[appleResponseCallback1]")
}

val pearResponseCallback = (r: PearResponse) => {
  println("[pearResponseCallback]")
}

val anyResponseCallback = (r: Response) => {
  println("[anyResponseCallback] r is a " + r.getClass.getSimpleName)
  r match {
    case appleR: AppleResponse => // ...
    case pearR: PearResponse => // ...
    case pruneR: PruneResponse => // ...
  }
}
```

#### Identifiers

```
/* A couple of identifiers */
object appleCbId1 extends CallbackId[AppleResponse]
object appleCbId2 extends CallbackId[AppleResponse]
object pearCbId1 extends CallbackId[PearResponse]
object pearCbId2 extends CallbackId[PearResponse]
object someCbId extends CallbackId[Response]
```

#### Type-safe list of callbacks

```
/* Init list of callbacks */
val callbacks = HMap[CME](
  appleCbId1 -> appleResponseCallback1,
  appleCbId2 -> appleResponseCallback2,
  pearCbId1 -> pearResponseCallback,
  pearCbId2 -> pearResponseCallback,
  someCbId -> anyResponseCallback
)
```

#### First use case

```
val appleCb = callbacks.get(appleCbId1).get
val someCb = callbacks.get(someCbId).get

appleCb(AppleResponse()) /* Fine */
someCb(AppleResponse())  /* Fine */
someCb(PearResponse())   /* Fine */
// appleCb(PruneResponse()) /* Rejected by the compiler */
```

#### Introduce requests

```
abstract class Request[R <: Response] {
  def id: CallbackId[R]
}

case class AppleRequest(id: CallbackId[AppleResponse])
  extends Request[AppleResponse]

case class PearRequest(id: CallbackId[PearResponse])
  extends Request[PearResponse]

case class RandomRequest(id: CallbackId[Response])
  extends Request[Response]
```

#### Second use case

```
def handleAppleRequest(r: AppleRequest) {
  // Do something with the request

  // Phone home
  val cb = callbacks.get(r.id).get
  cb(AppleResponse()) /* Fine */
  // cb(PearResponse())  /* Rejected by the compiler */
}

handleAppleRequest(AppleRequest(appleCbId1))
```

Since the solution is type-safe (or at least tries to be), it might be more complicated to initialise the list of callbacks in a less "statical", environment, e.g., if callbacks are created by (weakly typed) factories or by reflection.

Comment: Wow... Very nice answer :) Looks a bit complex for me and I think it would be overkill in my case. Anyway I hope this answer will help anyone else. Thank you.

Comment: @Soteric Yeah, it is not the least complex one, I agree. But if you separate the code snippets into what has to be done behind the scenes and what the client in the end has to do, than the latter part turns out to be quite small. That is, the client only has to implement the callback and add it, together with an identifier, to the list of available callbacks.

Comment: Won't the approach with shapeless hit performance? Is there a big overhead?

Comment: @Soteric Short answer: I don't know. I assume not, since shapeless is mainly focused on precise static type information, which is work done at compile-time, not at runtime. There probably is some overhead due to implicit method calls and additional method call arguments (the implicit evidence arguments that are used to aid the type checker/inferer). However, I don't think that these cause a significant runtime overhead. If you search for the performance overhead of implicit methods you'll find plenty of resources, some of which claim that the JVM is basically able to remove those completely.

Comment: I didn't mention exact overhead in percents. Just wondered if any "heavy" operations like reflection or any extensively garbage generating methods are involved. If it's just a matter of few method calls then it's fine. I will take additional look on it and update later. Thanks for supporting.

Comment: @Soteric Should you benchmark both attempts I'd love to hear about it, please post the results here. AFAIK there is no reflection involved. I can't comment on the effect on the garbage collector, but as said before, I doubt that there are any significant ones.

Comment: I can't guarantee that I perform benchmark in near future. This is kind of home project I'm doing in free time (mostly for skill improvement purposes). But in case I finish prototype I'll share results, no doubt.